# Importing Data from large CSV File

Tags: mysql

I have a large CSV file that I can not completely open in excel.

I have a script to import this data into MySQL, the script converts some date columns and imports everything else:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'A:\\My Files\\Desktop\\SPX\\Book2.csv'
INTO TABLE spx_options_data2 
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@date, symbol, under, @expiration, strike, put_call, bid, ask, price, volume, open_interest, implied_vol, delta, gamma, rho, theta, vega, nonstd)
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%d/%m/%Y'), 
expiration = STR_TO_DATE(@expiration, '%d/%m/%Y'), 
implied_vol = IF(implied_vol = "",NULL,implied_vol);
```

When I try to import the whole file, most of the rows are skipped and the little data that is imported has the dates fields as 0000-00-00. A snippet of the error response MySQL provides is:

> **580 row(s)** affected, 64 warning(s):  …………1411 Incorrect datetime
>   value: '2014-01-02' for function str_to_date 1048 Column 'date' cannot
>   be null ……… 1411 Incorrect datetime value: '2014-01-18' for function
>   str_to_date……….  Records: 1333176  Deleted: 0  **Skipped: 1332596** 
>   Warnings: 7354726

However if I:

1. Open the csv file in excel
2. Copy all the data excel can open to another csv file
3. Try and import that file

I get better success:

> **1035456 row(s)** affected, 64 warning(s):  ………. 1292 Truncated incorrect
>   DECIMAL value: '' …………… 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '2014-01-02-SPX-1450-C-2014-01-18' for key 'PRIMARY' ……………. 1366
>   Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'implied_vol' at row 2262 …… 
>   Records: 1048575  Deleted: 0  **Skipped: 13119**  Warnings: 52540

**Questions**

1. What is the best way to import large CSV files into MySQL?
2. Why am I getting the different results above (1035456 rows been imported in the second case VS only 580 in the first) even though the data is from the same source and format?
3. Why are so many rows been skipped?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Did you verify that it is a valid csv file?

Comment: seems like you have some data quality issues - bad date formats, number formats and so on which you need to sort out before it can import all the rows. Possibly the disparity between the two imports is either because Excel did some sort of processing on the file before saving it. It's hard to say without having a sample of the two files available. Also Excel is not the only way to open a CSV, you can just look at them in a text editor such as Notepad++ in order to check them.

Comment: Hi all, just responding to some of the comments:
(1) yes its a valid CSV file, i.e. file properties says so.
(2) the data comes from an online financial database so it .. should.. be formatted the same.
(3) the part I copied and pasted is 76% of the file size of the original csv file so I would have expected any errors/formatting issues to be in a similar proportion.
(4) thanks I'll obtain Notedpad++ now

Comment: Good call @ADyson - when opening in Notepad++ II noticed that date format was different to what I was seeing in the CSV file. Although I am still getting 14,919 rows of skipped data or 1.1% of the data. Considering this comes from a quality data source I would have expected 0 errors. Is there anyway to see the data MySQL isn't importing? Thanks

Comment: I don't know any other way to see what's been skipped other than to look through the warnings. You'll probably find a recurring pattern of problems, hopefully one that's fixable. And just because your data source is "quality" doesn't mean it's immediately compatible with what MySQL is expecting :-). Dates in particular are always a bugbear.

Comment: @ADyson - correct again! Thanks. I fixed up some primary key issues, 100% success now.

Comment: @TejayLovelock cool glad you were able to sort it. Sometimes it's just a case of trial and error, or working through each issue one at a time. Boring but effective!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ADyson:

> Q1. What is the best way to import large CSV files into MySQL?

View the file in Notepad++ to ensure formatting is as expected, in particular with dates.

> Q2. Why am I getting the different results above (1035456 rows been imported in the second case VS only 580 in the first) even though the data is from the same source and format?

Don't know, doesn't matter, its fixed.

> Q3. Why are so many rows been skipped?

Primary Key issues were preventing data from been imported. Once again, viewing in Notepad++ and noticing some problems resolved the issue.